# Intercambiar e-nésimo bit de un unsigned * x en C

Tags: c

Necesito modificar el bit de la posición N de un `unsigned int *`, podrían ayudarme?

```
void flip_bit(unsigned * x, unsigned n) {
    //Necesito mi código aquí
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posible implementación sería:

```
void flip_bit(unsigned * x, unsigned n) {
    unsigned y = 1 << n;
    *x = *x ^ y;
}
```